# Can I change the default modifier from Friend to Private in the Windows Forms designer in VS 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

When I develop a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio using C#, every control that I add to my form is by default marked as **`private`**, which is what I want.

When using VB.NET, every control is by default marked as **`Friend`** (the equivalent of **`internal`** in C#), which is *not* what I want.

Can I just change this default? It seems like surely it's a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annoying, isn't it.

What I usually do is when the form is stable, I replace `Friend WithEvents` to `Private` then add `WithEvents` to the controls that have `Handles` clauses.

Yes, you would think there was a setting, but I never found it.

Comment: Looks like neither of us could find it. I'm accepting this answer now; maybe someday someone will come along and show us both what we've been missing ;)

Answer (score 3):

This was suggested to Microsoft, but they chose [not to fix it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/422409/setting-a-default-access-modifier-for-windows-forms-controls).

[Sorry, posting this as an answer because I don't have enough points to add comments.]