# Getting the value of the label from other form using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

It is not working, the labels only goes back into its default values. What do you think is the problem?

Okay this is my code:

Actually I'm using mysql as my database here

This is the form that generates the values of the labels:

```
Private Sub ProfileControl_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(ServerString)
        Dim dap As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from employee where LogInID = '" & Main.ID.Text & "'", conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dap.Fill(dt)

        employeenum = dt.Rows(0).Item("EmployeeID")
        position = dt.Rows(0).Item("Position")
        employeename = dt.Rows(0).Item("FirstName") + " " + dt.Rows(0).Item("LastName")

        lblemployeename.Text = employeename
        lblemployeenum.Text = employeenum
        EmpPosition.Text = position

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And this is the form that will retrieve the values of the 3 labels.

```
Private Sub addsavebutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addsavebutton.Click
    Dim profile As New ProfileControl


    If txtbranchname.Text <> "" Then
        If addsavebutton.Text = "ADD" Then

            Dim zero As Integer = 0
            Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO branch(BranchName,Centers)VALUES('" & txtbranchname.Text & "','0') "
            SaveCenter(SQLStatement)
            logdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            logdate2 = Format(Date.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd")
            status = "Added Branch " + txtbranchname.Text
            SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO log(EmployeeID,Name,EmployeePosition,Date,DateTime,Status)VALUES('" & profile.lblemployeenum.Text & "','" & profile.lblemployeename.Text & "','" & profile.EmpPosition.Text & "','" & logdate2 & "','" & logdate & "','" & status & "' )"
            Savelog(SQLStatement)
            txtbranchname.Clear()
        ElseIf addsavebutton.Text = "SAVE" Then
            Dim Query As String

            Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ServerString)
            con.Open()

            Query = "UPDATE branch SET  BranchName = '" & txtbranchname.Text & "' WHERE BranchCode = '" & txtbranchcode.Text & "'"


            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
            Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If (i > 0) Then

                'success
                Dim Successtext As New MsgSuccess
                Successtext.PassedText = "Record is Successfully Updated"
                Successtext.ShowDialog()


                Dim SQLStatement As String
                logdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                logdate2 = Format(Date.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd")
                status = "Updated Branch: " + txtbranchcode.Text + ", " + txtbranchname.Text
                SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO log(EmployeeID,Name,EmployeePosition,Date,DateTime,Status)VALUES('" & profile.lblemployeenum.Text & "','" & profile.lblemployeename.Text & "','" & Main.lbldate.Text & "','" & logdate2 & "','" & logdate & "','" & status & "' )"
                Savelog(SQLStatement)

                srchTextBox.Clear()
                con.Close()

            Else
                'error
                Dim Errortext As New Msgerror
                Errortext.PassedText = "Record is not Updated"
                Errortext.ShowDialog()



            End If


        End If
    Else
        Dim Errortext As New Msgerror
        Errortext.PassedText = "All Entries with * must be filled"
        Errortext.ShowDialog()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Since the controls on the form are private and you should keep it that way, you need to write 3 public properties, one for each label, that exposes the value of the controls' text.

Comment: Gah, the sql injection vulnerabilities, they burns us!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create an instance of your form2 in form1.

```
Dim secondform As New Form2
```

On your form2, go to the 'modifiers' property of your three labels and change it to public.

Then you can set variables in form1 to get the value of the labels like the following;

```
Dim a As String = secondform.lblemployeename.Text
Dim b As String = secondform.lblemployeenum.Text
Dim c As String = secondform.lblEmpPosition.Text
```

This should make 'a', 'b' and 'c' the value of your labels

Comment: You have to update the values if they change or a,b,c will keep the first value always.

Comment: Did it work then? Well thats for the OP to sort out. I've given a way to achieve what he has asked.

Comment: I've updated my answer if you need to access the controls on the other way. Anyway, in this manner, you should change a,b,c values from `lblName.TextChanged` event if you need to have the updated values.

Comment: Ok I have this addbutton click event in my FORM1, what it has to do is to retrieve the values of the labels from FORM2 and in FORM2 I had this  load event which generates the values of the labels. I've changed already the modifiers of the labels into public. So why is that it is not working?

Comment: I have just made a two form application in VS2010, VB.net and replicated my answer and it works fine. Post some code as it is now impossible to help further

Comment: Agree. Edit your question to add more code in order to us to help you more and find the problem.

Comment: Edit current question, rather than creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the controls from the form's name:

```
Form2.lblemployeename.Text
Form2.lblemployeenum.Text
Form2.lblEmpPosition.Text
```

For me, in VB.NET 2.0 with VS2005, the controls are created `Friend`. Check the form designer and put your controls on `Public` or `Friend` (and `With Events` if you need it) in order to use them from other forms.

Comment: @user2083771 because by default it's not Public.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just tried from a new project and its declared `Friend` by default, so it works =/. I use VS2005 and .NET 2.0

Comment: Weird, in C# it's different then. I was pretty sure the language doesn't matter on this subject.. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard True, i've just tried in C# and its `private` by default

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you are interested I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168711/can-i-change-the-default-modifier-from-friend-to-private-in-the-windows-forms-de

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating an instance of your form (`Dim profile As New ProfileControl`) and then you try to access his controls values. Dont you have a `ProfileControl` already created?

Anyway, if `ProfileControl` is a form, the `Load` event will only execute when the form loads (when you show the form), so the values for the labels are not getting loaded.

If you are showing the form already, dont create that instance and use the form name that you showed to access the labels.

If you are not showing the form, you should consider creating that values in another variables and later assign it to the labels or create your own class, etc.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake the ProfileControl is not a form rather it is a usercontrol.

Comment: Yes I'm showing the form already but how can I access the labels without creating that instance?

Answer (score 0):

A know this is a bit late, but I spended 2days to figure it out(I readed more then 100 pages from Google, stackoverflow, VBforums,..). Here si solution:

Create constants.vb (class) and put in code below:

```
Public Shared Property loading_window_status As String = ""
```

Now you can access loading_window_status from form1, form2.ShowDialog(), form3.Show().

form1:

```
constants.loading_window_status = "Test"
```

form2:

```
dim a as string
a = constants.loading_window_status
```

For me, nothing else is working, when I want to close loading_screen.ShowDialog() from loading_screen timer1.tick, but triger for closing is on form1.

**Example:**

```
Public Class form1
    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'set status to show
        Constants.loading_window_status = "Show"
        'multitreads for spinner to run on loading_screen
        Application.DoEvents()
        'use ShowDialog or System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf form_loader_window.ShowDialog), Me)
        loading_screen.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'close screen loader
        Constants.loading_window_status = "Close"
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public Class loading_screen

    Private Sub loading_screen(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Timer1.Interval = 500
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim what_todo As String
        'get status from "form1"
        what_todo = Constants.loading_window_state

        If what_todo = "Close" Then
        'if status close, close me (ShowDialog)
            Me.Close()
            Timer1.Stop()

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Tested on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview.